# Vaadin Grid (or Components) - Polymer 3 and ES Modules Compatible Version

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin-grid, polymer-3.x

How to upgrade official documentation Polymer 2 demo example to Polymer 3?

I'm trying to deploy [pagination-demo](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/html-examples/grid-pagination-demos) to [polymer3-webpack-starter](https://github.com/web-padawan/polymer3-webpack-starter), but it doesn't work. It seem's that paging functionality added in script element can not be part of custom components template in polymer 3 version...